# How to get your own facebook images with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, api

ive set the required permissions and gotten the path ie me/photos this displays:

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "78768",
      "from": {
        "name": "Dai beckham",
        "id": "135656456"
      },
      "picture": "link here",
      "source": "link here",
      "height": 540,
      "width": 720,
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 720,
          "width": 960,
          "source": "link here"
        },
```

i then try echoing the image paths like `echo $user_graph['data']['source'];` but im getting an error

"Notice: Undefined index: source in A:file-name.php on line 12"

i have no idea where im going wrong.  thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like `json`, have you converted it to an array first? `json_decode()`

Comment: If one of these answers helped you, remember to accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the response into an array before you can access it like that.

Currently it's in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. You can use the native [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) function to convert it for you.

```
$array = json_decode($response, true);

$source = $array['data']['source'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($response, true);  //it will provide array
$source = $array['data']['source']; and access it now
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply fetch from this url

http://graph.facebook.com/ankit.varia/picture

type your name instead of mine ankit.varia(me)= (your)